# Kotlin - list of elements where some have the same ID, needs to be grouped

Tags: android, kotlin, group-by

I've got a list of, let's say food dishes.
The data class looks like this:

```
data class FoodItem(val categoryId: Int, val categoryTitle: String, val title: String, val text: String)
```

So let's say I have this is as data:

```
val list = listOf(FoodItem(1, "Mexican", "Burrito", "Wrapped food"),
            FoodItem(2, "Italian", "Pizza", "Dough, cheese and tomato"),
            FoodItem(3, "BBQ", "Brisket", "Does it need explaining?"),
            FoodItem(4, "Japanese", "Sushi", "Raw fish and rice!"),
            FoodItem(2, "Italian", "Pasta", "Great with meatballs!"))
```

I want this to be grouped into a single list, where the ones where CategoryId and CategoryTitle match, are grouped.

So in the end I would like a list of 4 items, where the Italian category has 2 items in its own list. So I would imagine I need a new data class that can hold a Category, which contains the id and title, and then a list of FoodDescription or something that contains Pizza, Pasta, etc etc, all within the category it's in.

I would like an output something similar to this:

```
GroupedFoodItemViewModel(category=Category(categoryId=2, categoryTitle=Italian), foods=[FoodItemViewModel(categoryId=2, categoryTitle="Italian", foodTitle="Pasta", foodText="Great with meatballs!"), FoodItemViewModel(categoryId=2, categoryTitle=Italian, foodTitle=Pizza, foodText=Dough, cheese and tomato)])
```

Where the rest would be in a list similar to this, just with one element under the "foods" array. I'd like to use this in a recyclerview, where I have the category as a title and the list of foods in below the category.

Comment: Can you please post the output you want? We can help you better this way.

Comment: @iCantC Sorry, I've tried explaining better. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a 1:1 correspondence, I would not recommend having redundant properties for category ID and title. That is inviting error. You should have a constant map of IDs to titles somewhere, and the class can pull in the title that way:

```
val CATEGORY_IDS_TO_TITLES = mapOf(1 to "Mexican", 2 to "Italian", 3 to "BBQ", 4 to "Japanese")

data class FoodItem(val categoryId: Int, val title: String, val text: String) {
    val categoryTitle: String get() = CATEGORY_IDS_TO_TITLES[categoryId] ?: error("Unknown category ID")
}

data class Category(val categoryId: Int) {
    val categoryTitle: String get() = CATEGORY_IDS_TO_TITLES[categoryId] ?: error("Unknown category ID")
}
```

Then, given your class that combines a category with a list:

```
data class GroupedFoodItemViewModel(val category: Category, val items: List<FoodItem>)
```

you can use `groupBy` on your original list to collect the separate lists based on the category ID, and then map the entries of the generated `Map<Int, List<FoodItem>>` into a list of GroupedFoodItemViewModel:

```
val grouped = list.groupBy(FoodItem::categoryId)
    .entries.map { (id, itemList) ->
        GroupedFoodItemViewModel(Category(id), itemList)
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I did a poor job explaining how I want the end result - I've updated my question.

Comment: I revised my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I used the bottom part of your code, with the entires.map and it worked great with another data class. :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution for you. You said specifically you want to match your `CategoryId` and `CategoryTitle` so that's exactly what I did:

```
val groupedMap = list.groupBy{ Pair(it.categoryTitle, it.categoryId) }
groupedMap.entries.first().key.first //for the name e.g. "Italian"
```

So basically Kotlin offers in its `stdlib` a function called `groupBy` where you can `similarly to SQL` group a List by a given key. In your case the Key consists of two Properties (`CategoryId` and `CategoryTitle`). To use both as a Key you can either create a custom Class containing those props or use - as I did - a `Pair`. The second line of the code accesses the first entry of the resulting list - then the key of it (e.g. `Pair("Italian", 2)`) and with the `first` at the end you access the first property of the `Pair` (in that case the `CategoryTitle`).

Since your CategoryId seems to be correlated with your CategoryTitle you might be able to only group by CategoryTitle. This would then look like this:

```
val groupedMap = list.groupBy{ it.categoryTitle }
```

Then the name (e.g. Italian) would be the key of the resulting groupedMap.

---

**EDIT after changed requirements**

So basically you could do this:

```
val result = list.groupBy{ foodItem ->
    Category(foodItem.categoryId, foodItem.categoryTitle)
}

result.forEach { entry ->
    entry.value.map { foodItem ->
        with(foodItem) {
            FoodItemViewModel(
                categoryId,
                categoryTitle,
                title,
                text
            )
        }
    }
}

data class FoodItem(val categoryId: Int, val categoryTitle: String, val title: String, val text: String)
data class FoodItemViewModel(val categoryId: Int, val categoryTitle: String, val foodTitle: String, val foodText: String)
data class Category(val categoryId: Int, val categoryTitle: String)
```

All I am doing here is creating the `Category` (key) whilst grouping the elements. Then I only have to map the resulting value from `FoodItem` to `FoodItemViewModel`.

You may want to consider refactoring your classes a bit. The properties of `Category` also exist in `FoodItem` and `FoodItemViewModel`.

Hope this solves your problem :).

Comment: I'm sorry, I did a poor job explaining how I want the end result - I've updated my question.

Comment: I have edited my answer; now it should work fine :)

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow, and Mark as answered if it solves it! Thanks

Comment: Okay great thanks :)! If it doesn't work just comment (though I tried it) and I'll help you

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help - I ended up using another answer as the solution, the mapping was a bit more simple. Yours worked as well though, I tried it. Thanks a bunch for taking the time!

Comment: You're welcome :) It's totally fine. The other solution is really more convenient

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `groupBy`.

Please check below code:

```
data class FoodItem(val categoryId: Int, val categoryTitle: String, val title: String, val text: String)

val list = listOf(FoodItem(1, "Mexican", "Burrito", "Wrapped food"),
            FoodItem(2, "Italian", "Pizza", "Dough, cheese and tomato"),
            FoodItem(3, "BBQ", "Brisket", "Does it need explaining?"),
            FoodItem(4, "Japanese", "Sushi", "Raw fish and rice!"),
            FoodItem(1, "Italian", "Sushi", "Raw fish and rice!"),
            FoodItem(2, "Italian", "Pasta", "Great with meatballs!"))
val groupMap = list.groupBy{ Pair(it.categoryId , it.categoryTitle)   }
println(groupMap)
```

**Output:**

```
 {(1, Mexican)=[FoodItem(categoryId=1, categoryTitle=Mexican, title=Burrito, text=Wrapped food)], 
    (2, Italian)=[FoodItem(categoryId=2, categoryTitle=Italian, title=Pizza, text=Dough, cheese and tomato),
     FoodItem(categoryId=2, categoryTitle=Italian, title=Pasta, text=Great with meatballs!)], 
    (3, BBQ)=[FoodItem(categoryId=3, categoryTitle=BBQ, title=Brisket, text=Does it need explaining?)], 
    (4, Japanese)=[FoodItem(categoryId=4, categoryTitle=Japanese, title=Sushi, text=Raw fish and rice!)], 
    (1, Italian)=[FoodItem(categoryId=1, categoryTitle=Italian, title=Sushi, text=Raw fish and rice!)]}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I did a poor job explaining how I want the end result - I've updated my question.